# This is my first angularjs page and its not work with php

Tags: php, angularjs

I m following the video demo and i can't get the result like video demo..
my code is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
 <title>Angular Practice</title>
 <script
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js" >

 </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="TodosController">

<div>
 <label for="name"> Name: </label>
 <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
 <hr>
 <h1> Hello {{name}} </h1>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

and my output is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLi8T.png)

Comment: Do you have any javascript? You need javascript!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `ng-controller="TodosController"`. You haven't specified any controllers here!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
 <title>Angular Practice</title>
 <script
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js" >

 </script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
 <label for="name"> Name: </label>
 <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
 <hr>
 <h1> Hello {{name}} </h1>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```